# PHP replace parts of a string and get the those replaced parts as separate strings

Tags: php, string, str-replace

I have a string like, `"[one]sdasf[two]sad[three]"`

So, I want to replace [one] with `"replaced_one"`, [two] with `"replaced_two"`.
and I need those replaced values as separate strings.

```
$rep_one = "replaced_one";
$rep_two = "replaced_two";
```

Comment: Ok great. Your requirements are clear. Now what you have tried so far to overcome your problem?Please add your effort.Otherwise it seems like you are asking us to do code for you

Answer (score -1):

This is a simple PHP function `str_replace()` (For more info go to [PHP Manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php))

The function is expecting three parameters:

```
str_replace(
  # Search - string section to be replaced
  # Replace - the content which will replace the `Search`
  # Subject - The string you want to alter
)
```

So in your case you can simply do this:

```
$str = "[one]sdasf[two]sad[three]";
$str = str_replace('[one]', 'replace_one', $str);
$str = str_replace('[two]', 'replace_two', $str);

echo $str; // replace_onesdasfreplace_twosad[three]
```